# Flurry vs localytics?

Tags: iphone, android, ipad, ios4

what are the advantages and disadvantages in using Flurry or Localytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using flurry in your app you can trace your app, Suppose you want to track that this button pressed how many times ,You can use flurry it shows that in this location this app is used and that button is pressed that number of times.

DISADVantage:- Flurry is very slow it gives you results in 14-15 hours.

ADVANTAGE:- it is free

OTHER :- in place of flurry you can use google analytics(free) and omniture(Paid but give result faster)

you have to register yourself in flurry.com

Answer (score 15):

I can't answer about iOS, but the Android libraries for Flurry had a very half-baked feel to them when I tried them out about 3 months ago. There's a lot less power in their stats reporting and drilling down through the data can be like pulling teeth.

Additionally, I was getting wildly inaccurate session counts in a small closed beta test of my app (1000 sessions reported in a few minutes from one device). When I contacted Flurry support, it took them nearly a week to get back to me and then all I got was a fairly useless stock response. That alone knocked them straight off my list of potential analytics providers.

I've used Localytics on Android for hundreds of thousands of total installs at this point and am quite happy. Android gets treated as a first-class citizen (rather than feeling like a bolt-on on Flurry or even Google Analytics), and they have a pretty nice looking UI with a lot of good drilldown controls.

Answer (score 14):

Both services are free and both services provide the same basic functionality of providing app analytics (e.g. number of users, type of devices, how the users are interacting with the app, etc.).

I have used both services for Android, although I am currently using Localytics because the Localytics library is open source.  The Flurry library is closed source.  Open source has the advantage that you can modify the library, as well as see exactly what the library is collecting.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them store the data in public area. Although the data is so-called privacy, but it's not on your own server.

Comment: If you want to build your own server to collect data, Cobub Razor (http://github.com/cobub/razor)  is a good choice. It open sourced  for client SDK and server codes.

Answer (score 1):

Flurry is free but provides much less detailed information, and flurry also only accepts up to 10 parameters per event. Localytics makes it easy to sort your data in many ways. For example I can look at all my users for the past week, now I can view users per day, or per hour. Then I can split the data to show me which users that played in the last week started playing the game for the first time, and then I can view that chart scaled to 100%. I could then add a filter so that I'm only looking at data from the users that started on a specific date, or specific week, or even multiple specific dates/weeks/etc. There are only a few things that I'd like from the localytics website that they don't provide, like retention data for days 8-13, or 15-27, or past 28 days, but those things can all be done through SQL queries.

Basically, flurry is free, but basic compared to what you get from localytics. Localytics I believe is free up until 10k MAU (monthly active users). Using localytics over flurry has made a huge difference on the product I'm on, we have been able to make much better decisions based on data.